# Bisyllables ending in -ex/ix: Does the accusative stress always fall on the same part?

Tags: romance-languages

Bisyllables ending in x. Does the accusative stress always fall on the same part as
Felix-Felīcem
Helix-Helicem(strangely in Italian it results Hêlica) Fenix-Fenīcem (Fenîce)
Syrex-Syrīcis (Sírice in Spanish)?

Answer (score 9):

There are no native words in *-ĭx*, only in *-īx*, with a long vowel. It's not necessarily clear whether that's a regular development or just a coincidence—almost all of these words are feminine agent nouns (*genetrīx*, *amātrīx*, &c.) or other feminines (*iūnīx*; probably also *fēlīx*, which, though it is an adjective, must have a complicated etymological history) containing the same suffix continuing PIE **-ih₂-* > *-ī-*, and AFAIK the remainder just have no clear etymology (*pernīx*). Either way, the long vowel means these words will have a heavy penultimate syllable in the "inflected" forms other than the dative and ablative plural, and because of the way Latin stress works, that syllable will be stressed:

|  | sg. | pl. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nom. | **cor**nīx | cor**nī**cēs |
| voc. | **cor**nīx | cor**nī**cēs |
| acc. | cor**nī**cem | cor**nī**cēs |
| gen. | cor**nī**cis | cor**nī**cum |
| dat. | cor**nī**cī | cor**nī**cibus |
| abl. | cor**nī**ce | cor**nī**cibus |

The same does not apply to words in *-ĕx* (there are no words in *-ēx*): the short vowel (which degrades to -ĭ- in the "inflected" stem) and the fact that no nominal ending (other than the nominative singular) starts with a consonant means all "inflected" forms have a light penultimate syllable, so the accent falls on the antepenult:

|  | sg. | pl. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nom. | **cī**mex | **cī**micēs |
| voc. | **cī**mex | **cī**micēs |
| acc. | **cī**micem | **cī**micēs |
| gen. | **cī**micis | **cī**micum |
| dat. | **cī**micī | cī**mi**cibus |
| abl. | **cī**mice | cī**mi**cibus |

For both words in *-īx* and words in *-ĕx*, this applies generally, not just for bisyllables.

Two of your words aren't native Latin words: *helix* is from Greek ἕλιξ, and *fenix* (more commonly *phoenix*) is from Greek φοῖνιξ (*syrex*, though it looks like a Greek loan, is actually properly *sirex*, and the genitive is *sirĭcis*, not *sirīcis*). Greek has a different history and the -ι- in both ἕλιξ and φοῖνιξ is short. Whether this translates to a short *-i-* in Latin varies: L&S claim [yes for *helix*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dhelix) but [no for *phoenix*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dphoenix3), with commensurate implications for the locations of the accent.

Comment: I'm sorry: Sirex (as it results in Spanish "Sîrice") https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirex

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH ;)

Comment: BTW, the correct Italian spelling is _elica_ (_èlica_ only in teaching material) and it doesn’t come directly from _helĭce(m)_ but from a secondary form _(h)elĭca(m)_ which, being a feminine, had made into the first declension.