# For what Vulpes --> Vulpecula, but Sorex never will be Soreculus

Tags: derivation, diminutive

Vulpes --> Vulpecula, all right, but:

Sorex --> Soriculus, not Soreculus

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soriculus

Answer (score 9):

Latin has various diminutive suffixes. Although both words are spelled with "cul", the "c" in *vulpēcula* is part of the diminutive suffix, while the "c" in *sō̆riculus* is part of the root of the base word. We don't have **sō̆reculus* because the orginal noun *sō̆rex* doesn't have an *e* after the *r* in forms like *sō̆ricis, sō̆rices, sō̆ricum* (i.e. we don't have forms like **sō̆recis,* etc.)

#### The formation of *Soriculus*

The third declension noun *sō̆rex* has the genitive singular *sō̆ricis* (since the vowel [alternation between short *e* in the nominative singular and short *i* in the other forms is usual for words whose nominative singular ends in *-ex*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18776/bisyllables-ending-in-ex-ix-does-the-accusative-stress-always-fall-on-the-same)). If you take off the *-is* from the genitive singular form, you get *sō̆ric-.* Then add *-ulus,* and you get *sō̆riculus.*

I think *Sō̆riculus* may have first been coined as a taxonomic name (it doesn't seem to be in any Latin dictionary, although I was able to find [an example of *soriculorum* being used outside of binomial nomenclature](https://books.google.com/books?id=GbhfAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA588&lpg=PA588&dq=%22soriculorum%22&source=bl&ots=KHpmGzBIqZ&sig=ACfU3U315S9tH1nlRQWFOBBpA53ZysOwPA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5q-zogqX6AhXVMEQIHYd0AyUQ6AF6BAgFEAM#v=onepage&q=%22soriculorum%22&f=false)) so it isn't really the same kind of linguistic evidence as words that native Latin speakers formed themselves. However, it does seem to be regularly formed: *[The Formation of Latin Diminutives of Nouns and Adjectives](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323534846_The_Formation_of_Latin_Diminutives_of_Nouns_and_Adjectives),* by Ian Andreas Miller, says that third-declension nouns with stems ending in *-c-* regularly form diminutives with *-ul-* (page 11).

#### The formation of *vulpēcula*

The third declension noun *vulpēs* has the genitive singular *vulpis;* take off the *-is,* you get *vulp-.*

Aside from the genitive singular, the nominative singular is also sometimes relevant to the formation of Latin diminutives, and it is in this case: third-declension nouns with nominatives ending in *-ēs* (which are mostly feminine) often form diminutives in *-ēcula* (Miller page 14). Miller notes that, just as some words with nominatives ending in *-ēs* have variants ending in *-is* (so in addition to *vulpēs* we can find *vulpis* used as a nominative singular) some of the derived diminutives of words of this kind end in *-icula* instead of *-ēcula.*

The form *[vulpiculus](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/vulpiculus)* is listed by the *Dictionary of Medieval Latin from British Sources* as a synonym of *vulpēcula.* We can view this variant as being formed as *vulp-iculus* or *vulpi-culus.* Aside from showing *-icul*- instead of *-ēcul-,* this form has a different gender from *vulpēcula.* It's regular in Latin for a diminutive to match the gender of its base, and since *vulpēs* in Classical Latin is feminine, we expect its diminutive to be also. Variability in the gender of nouns for animals is not too uncommon, so it is not strange that either *vulpēs* or its diminutives were used as masculine nouns at some point in history, but for Classical Latin, it seems safest to stick to the feminine gender for *vulpēs*, and therefore to the ending *-cula* in its diminutive. (It is possible but not common for the diminutive gender-matching rule to be broken.)

If we were starting from a word **sō̆rēs, sō̆ris* f., then a diminutive form **sō̆rēcula* would not be unexpected.

Comment: One issue that's not addressed, and I think was addressed elsewhere before, is that we have Classical attestations of *musculus* and *paterculus* that don't go off the genitive. Perhaps if not here then your other post could account for the former two?

Comment: @cmw: A complete description of Latin diminutive formation would be pretty long (as the linked guide by Miller seems to indicate). I tried to avoid outright saying here that diminutives are always built on the stem found in the genitive singular form, since as you say that's not true. But I don't know of any simple way to describe which stem they are built on.

Comment: I don't think anyone does! It perhaps even changed over the years (my guess, but I don't think we can get that from textual information). Just thought it was worth mentioning considering they both had a particular kind of diminutive ending.

Answer (score 0):

The diminutive is formed from the genitive stem and the genitive of *sorex* is *soricis*.

The genitive of *vulpes* is *vulpis* so the diminutive can definitely be *vulpiculus* and it is so found in many manuscripts. For example, in the *Codex Pithoeanus*, the most important manuscript of Phaedrus' Fables, the spelling *vulpiculus* is used.

In general, formation of diminutives has a range of variation [as has been discussed previously on this site](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/constructing-latin-diminutives).

Comment: I don't have access to a modern critical edition of Phaedrus' fables right now, but it would be very surprising to me if the Codex Pithoeanus used *vulpiculus*; Pithou's own editio princeps certainly doesn't—it has *vulpecula*. Can you provide some evidence? *Vulpiculus* was certainly in use in some variety of Vulgar Latin at some point post-classically (it's the reconstructed ancestor of French *goupil*), but I've never seen it without an asterisk before it. (Also the genitive of *vulpes* is *vulpis*.)

Comment: @Cairnarvon The Codex Pithoeanus has vulpiculus, but don't let that stop you from downvoting me.

Comment: @Cairnarvon FWIW, Holder's edition of Pomponius Poryphyrio's commentary on Horace's *Epsistulae* has [*vulpiculae*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=vulpic). I don't have a critical edition of that text, though, so I can't say what he's basing that off. Certainly Guaglianone has *vulpec-* in Phaedrus.

Comment: TD: Not everyone who asks for evidence is downvoting you. I didn't, but I doubt C. did here, either, considering it was downvoted long before his comment. C.'s question is valid: I too wonder why it's *vulpiculus* in the *Codex Pithoeanus* if Pithou's *editio princeps* has *vulpecula*. I don't have an apparatus criticus for Phaedrus' text handy, so I can't say, but it is surprising.